# getting the index while interating a list

Tags: python, list, loops

while i'm interating a list, how can i get the id of the current item to reference it to list methods?

```
xl = [1,2,3] # initial list
yl = [3,2]   # list used to remove items from initial list

for x in xl[:]:
    for y in yl:
        if x == y:
            xl.pop(x) # problem
            break
        print x, y
print xl
```

in the simple example, i want to loop through the 2 lists, and when i find a similar item, remove it from list 1.

What should i use instead of X in the line commented with "#problem"?

PS: Note it's a copy i'm iterating from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general way to do this is with `enumerate`.

```
for idx, item in enumerate(iterable):
  pass
```

But for your use case, this is not very pythonic way to do what you seem to be trying.  Iterating over a list and modifying it at the same time should be avoided.  Just use a list comprehension:

```
xl = [item for item in xl if item not in yl]
```

Comment: +1 for enumerate but to clarify, its ok to modify a list while looping in terms of changing the value of indexes but not the size of the list. Though doing it over a copy is safe though maybe not efficient.

Answer (score 4):

How about `xl = [x for x in xl if x not in y]`

This is known as a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: it was a 'simple example'. it will require http requests and what not to make the check, not just matching two numbers.

Comment: @gcb That's not a problem. You can check as much as you want, with `xl = [x for x in xl if checkHttpRequestsAndWhatNot(x)]`, or shorter `x1 = filter(x1, checkHttpRequestsAndWhatNot)`.

Comment: that's a good point... think i will review the structures  i'm using right now.

Comment: It sounds as if you didn't really ask the question that you wanted answered.  You might update the question to make it more precise.  When you ask a simple question, you'll often find there is a simple answer available.

Comment: the answer about enumerate answered the question just right, but you and phihag raised a good point about using list comprehension and a bunch of functions instead of a flag and a bunch of loops. but it's sideways to the question, i think

Answer (score 2):

Instead of removing elements you don't like, you should simply use [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter):

```
x1 = filter(x1, lambda x: x not in y1)
```

Alternatively, a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) works as well:

```
x1 = [x for x in x1 if x not in y1]
```

If y1 is very large, you should look up in a set, like this:

```
y1set = set(y1)
x1 = filter(x1, lambda x: x not in y1set)
```

For reference, `pop` takes an index, and the generic way to get an index is [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate). However, in nearly all cases, there's a shorter and cleaner way to write the code than using indices.

Comment: this is really a mapping to a database. so in this case i want to keep the indexes. in my business logic, when i remove from the DB, i will remove from the in memory list. think i will end up using explicity indexes matching the DB...

Comment: @gcb If you want to keep the indices, you shouldn't be using `pop`, but setting the entries in the `x1` list to some marker value such as `None`.

Comment: i want to drop the indexes too.

Comment: @gcb Well, then simply use `filter`. Sorry, but I don't understand why you desperately want to call `pop`. `pop` is extremely slow by design, since it needs to copy a large part of the list and potentially reallocate the list afterwards.

Comment: i'm using it as sort of queue, so it may be slower, but it's the best analogy to not make the code too esoteric when i read it later :) but i may review that to use list comprehension instead of a queue.

Comment: It would also look better to use `ylset.__containts__` instead of `lambda x: x not in y1set`.

Comment: @ovgolovin Why's that? Double-underline methods are not supposed to be called from Python programs (and I assume you mean `__contains__`)